# Prove the following problem concerning...

Tags: geometry

Can you please help me prove the following statement: BD*CD=CF*AF+BE*AE based on this image :[image]

Where AD is the altitude and ED, DF the same. Triangle ABC is a arbitrary right angled triangle.

Thank you a lot!

Comment: ABC is isoscele?

Comment: No, its an arbitrary triangle

Comment: Truly arbitrary ? It looks rectangle (you drew a square in A). Edit : woops you wrote it already

Comment: Excuse me for deceptive image, but it's an arbitrary right angle triangle.

Comment: Geometric mean theorem may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I was amazed by what a easy problem it really was. I noticed, thanks to Sawarnik, that in each triangle, with its respective altitudes, we can use the geometric mean theorem, so we find that ED(square)+DF(square)=AD(square). Once I observed this, an ideal idea came to my mind, I noticed that ED=AF because we see that in quadrilateral EDFA all angles are right angles. So , from triangle ADF we have the result, using Pythagoras theorem !!!:)